# Скалирование размеров в QPainter & QPrinter

Tags: c++, qt

есть необходимость отрендерить таблицу с виджета в pdf, делаю это при помощи связки QPrinter&QPainter, при отрисовке есть проблема со скалированием размеров, в pdf они получаются ~ процентов на 10% больше. Каким образом можно решить данную проблему? Есть подозрения на то, что неправильно рассчитываю коэффиценты для QPainter, заранее благодарю за ответ.

P.S. Нет возможности использовать QWidget::Render()

P.P.S С QPdfWriter та же самая ситуация

Изображения виджета и pdf:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Код для перетаскивания таблицы из QTableWidget в pdf:

```
    QPrinter printer(QPrinter::HighResolution);
    printer.setOutputFileName("");
    printer.setPageSize(QPrinter::A4);
    printer.setFullPage(true);

    QPainter painter(&printer);

    const auto logicalDeviceDpiX = printer.logicalDpiX();
    const auto logicalDeviceDpiY = printer.logicalDpiY();

    auto screen = QApplication::screens().at(0);
    const auto logicalScreenDpiX = screen->logicalDotsPerInchX();
    const auto logicalScreenDpiY = screen->logicalDotsPerInchY();

    const auto scaleWidth = logicalDeviceDpiX / logicalScreenDpiX;
    const auto scaleHeight = logicalDeviceDpiY / logicalScreenDpiY;

    painter.scale(scaleWidth, scaleHeight);


    qDebug() << "Logical: ";
    qDebug() << "Printer dpix: " << printer.logicalDpiX();
    qDebug() << "Printer dpiy: " << printer.logicalDpiY();

    qDebug() << "Physical";
    qDebug() << "Printer dpix: " << printer.physicalDpiX();
    qDebug() << "Printer dpiy: " << printer.physicalDpiY();

    qDebug() << "Logical: ";
    qDebug() << "Table widget dpix: " << tableWidget->logicalDpiX();
    qDebug() << "Table widget dpiy: " << tableWidget->logicalDpiY();

    qDebug() << "Physical";
    qDebug() << "Table widget dpix: " << tableWidget->physicalDpiX();
    qDebug() << "Table widget dpiy: " << tableWidget->physicalDpiY();

    auto rowOffset = 0.0f;
    auto columnOffset = 0.0f;

    QPen pen(Qt::black);
    pen.setWidth(0);
    painter.setPen(pen);


    for (auto rowIndex = 0; rowIndex < rowCount; ++rowIndex) {

        auto rowHeight = tableWidget->rowHeight(rowIndex);
        columnOffset = 0.0f;

        for (auto columnIndex = 0; columnIndex < columnCount; ++columnIndex) {
            auto columnWidth = tableWidget->columnWidth(columnIndex);

            QRectF cellRect(columnOffset, rowOffset, columnWidth, rowHeight);
            painter.drawRect(cellRect);

            QFont font("Times", 12);
            QFontMetrics metrics(font);
            font.setPixelSize(metrics.height());
            painter.setFont(font);

            painter.drawText(cellRect, tableWidget->item(rowIndex, columnIndex)->text(), Qt::AlignHCenter | Qt::AlignVCenter);
            columnOffset += columnWidth;
        }
        rowOffset += rowHeight;
    }
```